# Android ICS - Force use of DroidSans as serif font

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts

Does someone know how to force the use of the DroidSans font in an android application as the sans font instead of Roboto?

Apparently there is a bug in the Roboto font, it does not display properly the accents, like in the following example:
лю́ди

Which display correctly (accent on the ю) with the serif font (which seems to be still the DroidSerif font), but not with the sans font (accent AFTER the ю)!

The new sans font appears to be Roboto, and I would like to use the DroidSans instead, which is displaying things properly.

Any easy solution to solve that problem?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Sébastien

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to manually add the DroidSans.ttf to your project and then set it to yout text fields.

Put the DroidSans.ttf in the assets folder in your project. Use this to aply it to all TextView´s (this example is when you have a bold font aswell):

```
public static void setDroidSans(final ViewGroup view,final  Context context){

    Typeface droidFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),  "fonts/DroidSans.ttf");
    Typeface droidFontBold=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),  "fonts/DroidSansBold.ttf");
    for (int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++) {
        checkForTextview(view.getChildAt(i),droidFont,droidFontBold);
    }   

}

private static void checkForTextview(View view, Typeface typeface, Typeface typefaceBold){
    if(view instanceof ViewGroup){
        ViewGroup v=(ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
            checkForTextview(v.getChildAt(i),typeface,typefaceBold);
        }
    }
    else if(view instanceof TextView){
        if(((TextView)view).getTypeface() == Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD)
            ((TextView)view).setTypeface(typefaceBold);
        else 
            ((TextView)view).setTypeface(typeface);
    }

}
```

Example of using it:

```
ViewGroup myRootView= (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.rootView);
setDroidSans(myRootView, getApplicationContext())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift answer and the code!
That was the only kind of solution I had been thinking about...
I think DroidSans should be available in the ICS system am I wrong? In that case isn't it possible to acess that resource without provding the font in the application?
Also no way to specify the font in style/xml files?
Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried putting this in your xml     android:typeface="sans"  ? But i think it will still be a variant of the Robot font..

Comment: This is exactly the problem: the robot font is apparently the sans variant, and there is no robot serif font. The robot font is buggy and does not support the accents correctly...